# How to set cookie using selenium in IE

Tags: selenium

How can i set cookie using selenium in IE. For Firefox and Chrome i am able to set cookie using createCookie method. But when tried the same method for IE, it is failing.

**Sample code used**

```
selenium.open("http://www.water.com");
selenium.createCookie("name=value", "path=/")
```

Comment: What error are you getting while trying to do this in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Switch off "Protected mode" in IE.

http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2011/08/trouble-with-protected-mode-in-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the bug by doing this instead:

```
selenium.getEval("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.cookie = 'name=value;path=/'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check IE driver version.
I resolved this problem by changing 64 -> 32 bit version driver.